# Why Exception class is checked as its child class RuntimeException is unchecked in Java?

Tags: java

In Exception hierarchy, RuntimeException is child class of Exception is unchecked but if we use Exception then it is treated as checked Exception why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation maybe?

Comment: Because that's how it was decided and designed.

Comment: Because that is the way they are defined in [JLS chapter 11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html).

Comment: Think of it as "being unchecked is inherited" instead of "being checked is inherited", and it will make sense.

Comment: @Kayaman: or that's how checked exceptions were kludged into Java ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba There were many design crimes committed back in the day... :)

Comment: thanks for your response. But how is it possible in case I want to create my custom exceptions in the same manner. If my parent custom Exception is extending Exception then how my child Exception can extend this custom parent Exception (Checked) and be UncheckedException as multiple Inheritance is not supported.

Comment: @JTalreja: If it was designed the way you seem to expect it (according to your original question), you would have the same problem. You can't make one decision (checked or unchecked) in the parent class and change it for subclasses. You always need 2 hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oracle Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html):

> Runtime exceptions can occur anywhere in a program, and in a typical one they can be very numerous. Having to add runtime exceptions in every method declaration would reduce a program's clarity. Thus, the compiler does not require that you catch or specify runtime exceptions (although you can).

So they added RuntimeExceptions to deal with common run-time problems, without the hassle of [catching-or-throwing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) every single time.